# ggplot2 - box plot questions on misalignment

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, boxplot

I am having the following challenges making a plot:

1. I am trying to do a 'grouped' box plot - but it appears that the box plots are not showing up near the corresponding x axis group.  So It's not easy to see which group each plot belongs to.
2. I am trying to add in an icon for the 'mean' value which right now is a triangle.  However these aren't moving with the grouped boxplots.
3. I don't want the triangle icon for the mean value to show up in the legend - I can't figure out how to remove this.
4. Whenever I try to add text I just want one value either for the median or the mean - not something repeated 50x.

## Boxplot

[image: help]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(RColorBrewer)  
library(reshape2)

ggplot(tips, aes(x = day, y = total_bill, fill=sex)) +  #grouping factor, y variable
       geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 1.2)) + # how to color
       labs(title ='Barchart Plot', x=' xaxis label',y='ylabel') +
       scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2")+ #use Dark2, Paired, Set1
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black",size=14,angle=45,
                                        hjust=.5,vjust=.5,face="bold"),
             axis.text.y = element_text(colour="grey20",size=16,angle=45,
                                        hjust=1,vjust=0,face="plain"),
             axis.title.x = element_text(colour="grey20",size=12,angle=45,
                                         hjust=.5,vjust=0,face="plain"),
             axis.title.y = element_text(colour="blue",size=16,angle=90,
                                         hjust=0.5,vjust=.5,face='bold')) +
       stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=17, size=4) +
       theme_base() +
       geom_text(label='just the mean or median please - number only')
```

Comment: Instead of `geom_text` you should use `stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="text", label = 'mean', position = position_dodge(width = 1.2))`